# ASP.NET MVC3 - Windows Authentication combined with login screen

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have a MVC3 mobile intranet site targeted, among others, towards tablet devices (iPad).
When I open the site on an iPad, I get a pop-up screen asking for logon credentials. I cannot in any way cache these credentials, so every time this application is opened the user is prompted for their credentials.

Since it's not possible to include an iPad in a Windows Domain (as far as I know), is there any way at all to get a login screen using Windows Authentication, making it possible to cache credentials and maybe maintain the session over longer periods of time so that the user will not have to re-enter their credentials when opening the site ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible as that's what Exchange OWA does. These articles may be of use: http://helios.ca/2009/05/04/aspnet-mvc-forms-authentication-with-active-directory/ & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx

Once authenticated via the form you can just add a session/cookie to maintain the session.